# Set and reset on rising and falling edge

Tags: vhdl

How to set a bit on rising edge and reset that bit on falling edge of a clock signal?
I would like to know how i can achieve the same. Depending upon a condition i want to set on rising edge and reset on falling edge. It's like getting clock pulse itself at the output.

I implemented for two different clock pulses but i am getting glitches like these.

[image]

My code for same is as this

```
process(clk)
begin 
   if rising_edge(clk) then
      d0 <= new_data;
   end if;
end process;

process(clk)
begin 
   if falling_edge(clk) then
      d1 <= new_data;
   end if;
end process;

out <= d0 when clk = '1' else d1;
```

[image]

Comment: Cold you post you're code for that? It look like you have multiple drivers on the 3rd signal.

Comment: See i added the code part. You were correct about multiple drivers, i corrected it now

Comment: Ok i got a workaround. Instead of using  d0 and d1 as signals i defined them as shared variables and glitches go away.

Answer (score 1):

If you want DDR data, which is the only time I can see that you'd actually want to do this, there are a number of ways of modelling it. If you want synthesis, instantiate the appropriate vendors primitive

However, for a model:

```
process(clk)
begin
   -- you could use this
   if clock'event = '1' then
      bit <= new_data;
   end if;
   -- or this
   if rising_edge(clk) ot falling_edge(clk) then
     bit <= new_data;
   end if;
end process;
```

You could also model it as 2 processes and a mux

```
process(clk)
begin 
   if rising_edge(clk) then
      d0 <= new_data;
   end if;
end process;

process(clk)
begin 
   if falling_edge(clk) then
      d1 <= new_data;
   end if;
end process;

out <= d0 when clk = '1' else d1;
```

Comment: Why "rising_edge(clk) ot falling_edge(clk)"? Are you sure "ot" wasn't supposed to be "or"? Besides, I thing checking for a signal multiple times in the same process can't be synthesized.

Comment: Read the answer in its entirety

Answer (score 0):

Having now seen your waveform, you could do the following to get a glitch free pulse train

```
process(clk)
begin
    if falling_edge(clk) then
       if pass_next_clock = '1' then
          mask <= '1';
       else
          mask <= '0';
       end if;
    end if;
end process;

pulse <= clk and mask;
```

This requires you to have a signal called pass_next_clock, which can be aligned to either clock edge to signal that you want the next clock high pulse to be output.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i got it work. My final code looks like

```
shared variables d0 ,d1 : std_logic;
process(clk)
begin 
   if rising_edge(clk) then
      d0 := new_data;
   end if;
end process;

process(clk)
begin 
   if falling_edge(clk) then
      d1 := new_data;
   end if;
end process;

out <= d0 when clk = '1' else d1;
```

[image: Final waveform]

Comment: Shared variables are a bad idea - the scheduling of the updates is completely unpredictable.